# linkedlist will add replace?

Tags: java, replace, linked-list, addition

For example, I have a LinkedList

```
LinkedList <E> ll
```

and it contained 2 items which means `ll.get(0)` and `ll.get(1)` will **not** return `null`.

If I do this now:

```
ll.add(1, "abc");
```

will the original item in `ll.get(1)` be replaced or will it move up to the position of `ll.get(2)`?

Comment: Let us read the documentation! http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#add%28int,%20E%29

Comment: The documentation for [List.add](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add%28int,%20E%29) is pretty clear about this. It's also easy to try for yourself...

Comment: alright thanks i just saw that

Comment: Method LinkedList.size() will tell you the answer.

Comment: OP, you seriously need to learn to read the documentation or you could have simply made a little program to try it out yourself.

Answer (score 0):

According to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html

> public void add(int index,
>          E element):
>
> Inserts the specified element at the specified position in this list. Shifts the element currently at that position
>   (if any) and any subsequent elements to the right (adds one to their
>   indices).

So, the original item is shifted.